# Node Mysql On Duplicate Key Update only updates unique row

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am using **MySQL 5.7** with **Node JS 6.11.0** and am trying to update a `UNIQUE` MySQL column whenever I insert a conflicting row. However, when I try inserting a conflicting record, only the existing record is updated to `NULL` and no `insert` happens. Here is my code

```
     pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var newClass = req.body;
        var query = `INSERT INTO classes SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE teacher_id = NULL`;

        connection.query(query, newClass, function(err, result) {   
            console.log(result);
            if(result.affectedRows >= 1) {
                res.status(201).end();
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
        connection.release();
    });`
```

I have to run the query twice for the row to be inserted; the first time the conflicting column is set to null then when I run the same query again, the row is inserted since there are no conflicts.

I have taken the SQL generated and directly run it from MySql console and I still have to run the query twice for the new row to be inserted. I do not understand why it is behaving this way.

> Sql statement is

```
INSERT INTO classes SET `stream` = 'Red', `form` = '1', `teacher_id` = '7' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE teacher_id = NULL
```

My create table SQL is

```
| classes | CREATE TABLE `classes` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `form` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `stream` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `teacher_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `teacher_id` (`teacher_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `classes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teachers` 
      ( `id` ) 
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |`
```

Why is MySQL behaving this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO classes
        SET stream = 'Red', form = '1',teacher_id = '7'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE teacher_id = NULL;
```

Is telling MySQL when there is a conflicting record (duplicate unique or primary key), to set the offending row's `teacher_id` column to `null` and stop.

You have a couple options to achieve your desired result.

First you can use the `REPLACE` syntax.

```
REPLACE INTO classes SET stream = 'Red', form = '1', teacher_id = '7';
```

Which will first delete the offending row with the UNIQUE or Primary Key constraint, and Insert a new row with the specified values. The drawback is any omitted column values would be lost and set to their default values. A new auto-generated (if any) id will also be created if not specified in the query.
If there is no offending record a normal `INSERT` will occur.

Otherwise, you can utilize `VALUES` within the `UPDATE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO classes
        SET stream = 'Red', form = '1', teacher_id = '7'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stream = VALUES(stream),
                            form   = VALUES(form);
```

This will instead, update the records of the offending row to the values specified in the `INSERT` portion of the query.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

---

**Updated based on new intentions**

In order to create a new record while leaving the previous row, you would need to first invalidate the `UNIQUE` constraint on the existing row, prior to using `INSERT`.
There is currently no method to do this with MySQL in a single query.

Due to limitations on `INSERT`, the easiest way to accomplish what you need is to run an `UPDATE` query prior to the `INSERT` query.

```
UPDATE classes 
   SET teacher_id = NULL
   WHERE teacher_id = '7';
INSERT INTO classes
   SET stream = 'Red', 
   form = '1',
   teacher_id = '7';
```

This will first check for a conflicting `teacher_id` record and set it to `null`. If no conflicting record exists, no update will occur. The following `INSERT` would then create the desired record, without a conflict occurring.

Comment: What I intended to achieve was to have the offending row updated first then a new row to be inserted. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: So @fyrye that means I have to enable `multiple statements` in MySQL for the query you have suggested to work.

Comment: @DennisWanyonyi You could execute the queries separately. There are alternatives to process the desired functionality in the same manner, such as a stored procedure to execute the queries or the use of triggers. But there's no single query operation to perform an `INSERT` and maintain the original row data, as you need to tell MySQL what to do with the conflicting row and you don't want to lose the association of classes to students on the class id.

Comment: how to pass a value in case of updating?

Comment: @sasuke please post your question on StackOverflow, so that we can get some more information to assist you better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert data based on condition try this

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT 'Red',1,7 FROM table2 where teacher_id IS NULL;
```

else if you want to update based on trying this.

```
update table1 SET stream = 'Red', form = '1', teacher_id = '7' where teacher_id IS NULL;
```

Note: NULL = NULL is not really FALSE - it's NULL again. But it's not TRUE either, so IF(NULL = NULL) won't execute
For example, NULL will test FALSE even against NULL itself. So, working with NULL is only done with the aforementioned functions (and IS NULL()). Your query could be rewritten as above.

Comment: Where did `table2` come from??

Comment: Sry its table1 only, my mistake.  But you can also  update parent nd child table with that query if we can set primary and foreign key relation.